# TypeError: Image is not a constructor

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) to upload images and all was working fine until I refactored my code. It's basically the same, but for some reason Plupload fails and gives me

```
TypeError: Image is not a constructor
```

when I try to upload an image ([error msg here](http://prntscr.com/587y0y)) . Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with my code? Plupload is starting and I can select image. It's when it tries to upload the image that it fails.

On my page, I have two areas where I can upload images.

```
var Image = {
    id: null,
    type: null,
    dropbox: null
};

ImageHandler = {
    settings:       {},
    image:          {},
    entityId :      null,       // ID of entity
    entity:         null,       // Entity type [store | brand | shmall | shguide]

    init: function(){
        var self = this;

        self.image.size             = { width:600,height:600,quality:80 };
        self.settings.url           = '';
        self.entityId               = lib.getEntityID(); // external function
        self.entity                 = $('.image-drop-box').data('entity-type');

        // For each image drop box area
        $('.image-drop-box').each(function(){
            var img             = jQuery.extend({}, Image);
            img.dropbox         = $(this);
            img.id              = img.dropbox.data('image-id');
            img.type            = img.dropbox.data('image-type');

            self.imageUpload(img);
            self.removeImageAction(img);
        });    
    },

    imageUpload : function(img) {
        var self = this;  // ImageHandler

        switch (self.entity){
            case 'guide':   self.settings.url ='/shguide/uploadImage'; break;
            case 'shmall':  self.settings.url ='/shmall/uploadImage'; break;
        }


        new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes : 'html5',
            container: img.dropbox.prop('id'),
            drop_element: img.dropbox.prop('id'),
            browse_button : img.type + '-file-browser-button',
            url :  self.settings.url,
            flash_swf_url: "vendor/plupload/Moxie.swf",
            urlstream_upload: true,
            max_file_count: 10,
            dragdrop: true,
            multipart_params : {
                'imageType' : img.type,
                'id' : self.entityId
            },
            file_data_name: 'Gallery[filename]',
            filters : {
                max_file_size : '5mb',
                mime_types: [{ title : "Image files",   extensions : "jpg,jpeg,png" }]
            },
            resize: self.image.size, // Resize images on client side if we can
            init : {
                FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                    up.start();
                },
                // Called when file has finished uploading
                FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(info.response);
                    // Do stuff here
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }).init();

        (...)
    }
}

ImageHandler.init();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your variable `Image` is causing the problem(Assuming it is in the global scope). In such case your `Image` object is overriding the default [Image constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image), now when some internal code is trying to create an image object using `new Image()` it is throwing the error.

Just rename your variable `Image` to something else.

```
var MyImage = {
    id: null,
    type: null,
    dropbox: null
};
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks for spotting that Arun.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error when I tried to instantiate the following code:

```
const img = new Image();
```

Problem is that I had already declared Image in the code below when I was running it through Bootstrap, thus the error. I hope this is useful to someone.

```
import {Row, Col, Button, Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is also an issue with 3.0beta1 causing this error. Fixed it by upgrading version.
https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/1406

Comment: `jayarjo added: the Fixed in coming release label on 19 Nov 2016`
Nice to know, thanks :)